# Navigation bar shows up on PopupMenu on immersive mode

Tags: android

I am creating a camera app with a popup menu for some camera settings. The problem is, when I click on the button that shows the popup menu, the bottom navigation bar appears. I've already searched through online for a solution, but non has worked for me thus far.

```
mChangeSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final PopupMenu changeSettingsPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(Camera2VideoImageActivity.this, mChangeSettingsButton) {
                @Override
                public void show() {

                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
                    super.show();

                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);


                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

                }


            };changeSettingsPopupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.change_setting_popup_menu, changeSettingsPopupMenu.getMenu());

            SubMenu changeImageResolutionSubMenu = changeSettingsPopupMenu.getMenu().addSubMenu(0, 100, 0, "Set Image Resolution ");
            SubMenu changeVideoResolutionSubMenu = changeSettingsPopupMenu.getMenu().addSubMenu(0, 101, 0, "Set Video Resolution");
            changeSettingsPopupMenu.show();
}
```

I also have this on my main activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/3oKIPh2W4bEQrGzmqQ" width="272" height="480" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/3oKIPh2W4bEQrGzmqQ">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

GIF of what happens:
http://gph.is/2rjPdny

EDIT:
Thanks Hitesh Gehlot for the reply! I get this when I try.
[This didn't work, Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGX8r.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this:

```
changeSettingsPopupMenu.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        changeSettingsPopupMenu.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());
 changeSettingsPopupMenu.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this but I got "cannot resolve getWindow()". Please check my edit on the original post for the screenshot.